# write to EditText field of Android Nested layout

Tags: java, android

I want to assign a variable to a nested layout EditText field

The layout flow is like this

activity_main.xml -> Linearlayout -> Linearlayout -> EditText

The name of layout used

LinearLayout -> main_layout -> position_layout ->EditText(id = @+id/floatdata)

I am a new to android I wish to write and read back from EditText

What is the best way to do it. Thank u

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initialize like

```
EditText editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.floatdata);
```

getData

```
editText.getText().toString();
```

setData

```
edittext.setText("Demo");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.IDNAMEHERE);
```

Setting data:

```
input.setText("Your string");
```

Retreiving data:

```
String inputvalue = input.getText().toString();
```